# Listing not printing inside " "

Tags: listings, sourcecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listings package not correctly showing PHP strings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11333/listings-package-not-correctly-showing-php-strings)

I'm using listings to include C code, but I've a problem: when I insert in the listing a **printf** like the following

```
  printf("inc_count(): thread \%ld, count = \%d  Threshold reached.\n", a,b);
```

The text inside the " .. " is not shown. I haven't found a way to fix this, I think it should be trivial and maybe I'm just using the wrong keywords... Can you help me?

EDIT:
Usage example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, label=cond-var, caption="Condition variables usage example"]
printf("inc_count(): thread \%ld, count = \%d  Threshold reached.\n", 
             my_id, count);
\end{lstlisting}
```

This is what is shown
[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also, you don't need to escape `%` inside a listing.

Comment: Your example works fine here, the quoted text is printed and everything looks as I would expect it to. Can you add a **complete** example, also showing the packages you load etc?

Comment: Until the MWE arrives, I'm going to guess that '\stringstyle' is set to a white color.

Comment: @MikeRenfro yes, that was the problem, I thought it was something I didn't knew about listings, instead there was a \stringstyle set to white in the preamble of my code. You can add your post as a reply, I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: This is the same issue as in [Listings package not correctly showing PHP strings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11333/listings-package-not-correctly-showing-php-strings)

Answer (score 3):

Given that your code worked fine for @wh1t3 earlier, that indicated a problem with something else in your document. I guessed that your listings options set the string style to white text on a white background, which you confirmed was true. Examples for future reference (also correcting the extraneous quotes around the caption, and the backslashes in the strings):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize,stringstyle=\color{white},language=C}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=cond-var-white, caption={Condition variables usage example}]
printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n", 
             my_id, count);
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{gray!50}}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=cond-var-gray, caption={Condition variables usage example}]
printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n", 
             my_id, count);
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{white},stringstyle=\color{black}}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=cond-var-black, caption={Condition variables usage example}]
printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n", 
             my_id, count);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```