# Listings remove single quotes after I made it look good

Tags: listings, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listings package not correctly showing PHP strings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11333/listings-package-not-correctly-showing-php-strings)

So I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books) code for my listings. However it seems to ignore single and double quotes and everything inside them and does not print it. Anybody have any idea why?

Here is the copy of the code if your too lazy to click :)

```
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{courier}
 \lstset{
         basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
         %numbers=left,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
         numberstyle=\tiny,          % Stil der Zeilennummern
         %stepnumber=2,               % Abstand zwischen den Zeilennummern
         numbersep=5pt,              % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
         tabsize=2,                  % Groesse von Tabs
         extendedchars=true,         %
         breaklines=true,            % Zeilen werden Umgebrochen
         keywordstyle=\color{red},
            frame=b,         
 %        keywordstyle=[1]\textbf,    % Stil der Keywords
 %        keywordstyle=[2]\textbf,    %
 %        keywordstyle=[3]\textbf,    %
 %        keywordstyle=[4]\textbf,   \sqrt{\sqrt{}} %
         stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
         showspaces=false,           % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
         showtabs=false,             % Tabs anzeigen ?
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         framexrightmargin=5pt,
         framexbottommargin=4pt,
         %backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
         showstringspaces=false      % Leerzeichen in Strings anzeigen ?        
 }
 \lstloadlanguages{% Check Dokumentation for further languages ...
         %[Visual]Basic
         %Pascal
         %C
         %C++
         %XML
         %HTML
         Java
 }
    %\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}} 

  %\captionsetup[lstlisting]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={blue}, textfont={blue}}
  \usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
```

Comment: `listings` considers strings to be denoted using single or double quotes and your `\lstset` includes `stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily`, which prints all strings in white. Remove this and things should return to normal.